# A calculator using Lua string matching

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I've recently playing around with string manipulation to try to make a calculator that takes only one string and returns an answer.  I know I could simply use loadstring to do this, but I am trying to learn more about string manipulation.  This is what I have so far:  Is there any way I can make it more efficient?

```
function calculate(exp)
    local x, op, y =
    string.match(exp, "^%d"),
    string.match(exp, " %D"),
    string.match(exp, " %d$")
    x, y = tonumber(x), tonumber(y)       
    op = op:sub(string.len(op))
    if (op == "+") then
        return x + y
    elseif (op == "-") then
        return x - y
    elseif (op == "*") then
        return x * y
    elseif (op == "/") then
        return x / y
    else
        return 0
    end
end

print(calculate("5 + 5"))
```

Comment: do you mean faster? fewer lines of code?

Comment: Fewer lines of code, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [captures](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.3.html) in the matching pattern to reduce the number of calls to string.match().

```
local x, op, y = string.match(exp, "^(%d) (%D) (%d)$")
```

This also eliminates the need to trim the `op` result.

The conversion `tonumber()` does not need to be called for `x` and `y`. These will automatically be converted when used with the numeric operators.

Comment: A pattern that allows liberal and optional whitespace and longer numbers is `"(%d+)%s*(%S+)%s*(%d+)"`.